# Java fix error with ZipEntry

Tags: java, zip

I wanted to create a function in java which compresses
a file into a .zip-file, using JFileChooser before.
And now ZipEntry can't get along with the absolute path which is "C:...\",
I know, that it needs `\\` instead of only `\`, but I
don't know how to do this.

Can anyone help me?

btw. here's the code:

```
public static void zip(String inputFile, String zipFile){
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        add(zos, inputFile);
        zos.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void add(ZipOutputStream zos, String fileName) throws Exception{
    File newFile = new File(fileName);
    if(newFile.exists()){
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(newFile);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0){
        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    zos.closeEntry();
    fis.close();
}}
```

Comment: What's your error? Always post your error. ALWAYS.

Comment: Do you use Java 7+? Also, it appears to me like you want to create a zip archive with only a single file, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is add a file to a zip archive then you're much better off using the zip filesystem provider available since Java 7+:

```
private static void addToZip(final String filename, final String zipfile)
    throws IOException
{
    final Path path = Paths.get(filename);
    final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + Paths.get(zipfile).toUri());
    final Map<String, ?> env = Collections.emptyMap();

    Path pathInZip;

    try (
        final FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystems(uri, env);
    ) {
        pathInZip = fs.getPath(path.getFileName().toString());
        Files.copy(path, pathInZip);
    }
}
```

Now, it is unclear what you want the path of the final zip entry to be, so...